# Function that gets mail in PHP

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to write in php such a script that will connect to a mail server like gmail.com  and get a mail from it ?

Maybe it sounds naive, but maybe there is a function that will do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There's the [IMAP library in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php).
A quick Google search [gave me an example](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap) of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is,
Please look into IMAP
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php